# Superfish dropdown with Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, superfish

How is it possible to combine the `nav-pills` of `bootstrap` and the `sf-menu` of `superfish`?

I simply tried to use them both.

`<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="example">
   <li class="sf-menu current"> menu item </li>
 </ul>`

.. but surely they conbtradicted each other in the css styles and the output wasn't useable. So now I am looking for an easy way, to combine both, without rewriting the css of either of them.

(I am beginner in front end programming)

Comment: Does it help? I can provide another few samples where I tried to change the `nav pills` and the `sf-menu` with each other or put them on some other places... and I can provide the output. For me it looks like I have two libs which are using the same resources, and because I am new in this area, I am looking for a smart way to combine both.